# Eclipse. Copy the Type Hierarchy into clipboard

Tags: eclipse

When I open "Type Hierarchy" in Eclipse (either <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>), is there any way to copy the result tree as text into the clipboard?

P.S. Print Screen is not a solution.

Comment: In what format do you want it copied? Text, Image, Object?

Comment: @adarshr I want it in text format.

Comment: `find . -name "*.class" | xargs javap | grep "extends com.abc.SomeClass" | sed -e 's/ extends.*//' | sed -e 's/public .*class //'`

Comment: I need the same thing. But found another way. Search (Java) for qualified type name + Search For: Type + Limit To: Implementors + Scope: Workspace >> Search View -> Group By Type -> Ctrl+A -> Copy Qualified Name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is available, either now or in the near future:

The [bug 108320](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108320) back in 2005 already mentioned that lack of feature and was asking for the ability to at least print the Type hierarchy... 
It has been closed as " RESOLVED WONTFIX".

Comment: Is there a bug filed for copy itself?  Copying is an "aside" in the original report that is not mentioned further in any comments.  I think the WONTFIX is for Printing from the view, and a new bug report is needed.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg I agree. I didn't find such a bug report yet.

Comment: I didn't find a bug and almost filed one, but I see now it's fixed in Eclipse Kepler.  It works in the type hierarchy, too.  (In Indigo, Juno and probably earlier, you can use Copy Qualified Name, but it doesn't work as well as the plain copying does now in Kepler.)

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg sounds great. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Sorry, I haven't got the point with "Copy Qualified Name"? How can I exactly copy the type hierarchy to the clipboard with "Copy Qualified Name"?

Comment: @MRalwasser It's in the context menu and applies to all lines you've selected, *but* I just discovered a much better, but very-hard-to-discover alternative!  Right-click on only the root of the hierarchy (or a sub-hierarchy) and select "Copy Expanded Hierarchy".  The option is invisible if you select multiple rows.

Comment: Hold on, I made a mistake.  Everything I said above applies to the call hierarchy, but not the type hierarchy.  At least in Indigo: the type hierarchy does not allow multiple selection (so Copy Qualified Name doesn't help this problem there), and there is no Copy Expanded Hierarchy option there.  Still useful for the call hierarchy, but doesn't address the original problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. Will it least work in Kepler? Otherwise, it would be great filing a bug.

Answer (score 9):

Copying the hierarchy still doesn't seem to be possible in Eclipse Neon.3, but you can use "Java Search" to work around this: enter the top-level type as the "Search string" and limit the search to "Implementors". You can then copy the search results.

Comment: I'm using Mars.2, but I'm also finding that it does not yet work

Comment: Unlike Type Hierarchy this approach will only go 1 level deep. i.e. showing only immediate child and not grandchild sub-classes