# Feature or keyboard shortcut in eclipse Kepler for copying type hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse

As per [Joshua Goldberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411282/joshua-goldberg) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353507/eclipse-copy-the-type-hierarchy-into-clipboard/5354312?noredirect=1#comment26924486_5354312) I interpret that you can copy the entire type hierarchy to clipboard. However I am unable to find the keyboard shortcut to do this, tried searching on [bug page](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108320).

Right now I select the classes one by one from type hierarchy that implement interface or extend a class, and copy them to text file, but I would guess there is a keyboard shortcut or feature to copy the entire hierarchy or even export it in some format. I just want to minimize the human error while listing all the classes.

Can somebody please point me to the right place. I am working on eclipse Kepler release build 20130614-0229, on Windows 7 64 bit.

Thanks.

EDIT: As per comment from [PopoFibo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2783244/popofibo) below, there does not seem a way to do this.

I would be under impression, that since the type hierarchy is shown as a tree, and someone parses and fills those data slots. It would be just another extension to export them as XML or text file. Too much wishful thinking.

Comment: He corrects himself later, no option to copy the type hierarchy yet. You can however copy the entire call hierarchy.